# How to add a file with Chinese characters to amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a json to be written to S3 from java. The json has a description field which is in Chinese. 
First I tried to write the json to a normal file and wrote it to S3. But the chinese characters were corrupted. Then I tried to write the json to a file with "UTF-8" and so used the below code

```
Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(f), "UTF8"));
byte[] bt = jsonData.toString().getBytes();
out.append(new String(bt));                     
out.flush();
out.close();
```

When I tried this the data was being written to the file correctly which I verified using Notepad++. But when I wrote it to S3 it was again corrupted. The worser thing is when such thing happens the object is getting removed from S3 if the file already exists. So, the issue is I have to write a file with chinese characters to S3 using java client and it should be stored as Chinese characters. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

For reference this is the json

```
    {"description":" شات اندرويد بمميزات جميلة يدعم شاشات الجوالات دعم كامل *امكانية رفع صورة عرض خآصة بكم *امكانية اظافة ايقونات واختصارات مثل : ض1, ض2 . الخ *امكانية تثبيت نك مع باسورد خاص ",
    "language":"","name":"شات فله العربي-new"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. What I did was, I wrote the json to a file as

```
    File f = new File(fileName);
        if (f.exists()) {
            f.delete();
        } else {
            f.createNewFile();
        }
    Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(f), "UTF-8"));
    byte[] bt = jsonData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
    out.append(new String(bt));
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    if (f.exists()) {
            PutObjectResult res = s3rwclient
                    .putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucket, key, f));
    }
```

This fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at https://github.com/minio/mc .

We support unicode characters out of the box for example.

```
$ mc ls https://s3.amazonaws.com/miniocloud/本語.txt
[2015-10-02 10:56:37 PDT] 5.8KiB 本語.txt
```

'mc' is also supported for Linux, OS X and Windows. Please provide us your feedback and any issues at https://gitter.im/minio/minio.

Comment: Hi Harshavardhana, I am not getting what is minio and how it will help me in resolving my issue. Is this a tool to upload the file to S3 using commandline?

Comment: 'mc' is a command line tool which you can use to upload files to s3 or anything s3 compatible cloud storage.